# Join columns of several dataframes into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of dataframes. Each of these dataframes has a column 'defrost_temperature'. What I want to do is make one new dataframe that collects all those columns, maintaining them as seperate columns.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
merged_defrosts = pd.DataFrame()
for key in df_dict.keys():
    merged_defrosts[key] = df_dict[key]["defrost_temperature"]
```

But unfortunately, only the first column is filled correctly. The other columns are filled with NaN as shown in the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVw77.png)

The different defrosts are not necessarily the same length. (the fourth dataframe is 108 rows, the others are 109 rows)

Comment: Some samples of your input dataframes and of your dict might help to understand the nature of your issues. Also, your desired output to make a [mcve]

Comment: This question needs more information. Are all the dataframes of equal length row wise?

Comment: One solution is to initialize `merged_defrosts` with the correct number of columns and enough rows to contain the longest array you need to put into it, fill it with `NaN` and finally replace `NaN`s with your data. This way, you can accomodate arrays of different lengths in a dataframe: the empty spaces will be `NaN`s.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: _The different defrosts are not necessarily the same length. (the fourth dataframe is 108 rows, the others are 109 rows)_ How do you know which value corresponds to which row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pd.merge` on index of the larger.

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
for i, df in enumerate(df_dict.values()):
    s1, s2 = f'_{i}', f'_{i+1}'
    m1, m2 = df_result.shape[0], df.shape[0]
    if m1 == 0:
        df_result = df
    elif m1 >= m2:
        df_result = df_result.merge(df, how=left, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=(s1, s2))
    else:
        df_result = df.merge(df_result, how=left, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=(s2, s1))
```

This would create undesired column names though that you can manually rename them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to concat the dataframes horizontaly after making the common column the index:

```
merged_defrosts = pd.concat([df.set_index("defrost_temperature") for df in df_dict.values()]
                            ).reset_index()
```